# Is my solution using L'Hospital's rule wrong?

Tags: calculus, limits

The limit I have is the following:
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to3^{+}} \frac{\ln(x-3)}{\ln(x^{2} - 9)}. $

I applied L'Hospital's rule which gave me:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to3^{+}} \frac{\frac{1}{x-3}}{\frac{1}{x^{2} - 9}} = \lim_{x\to3^{+}} \frac{1}{x-3} \cdot \frac{(x-3)(x+3)}{1} = \lim_{x\to3^{+}}\frac{(x-3)(x+3)}{(x-3)} = \lim_{x\to3^{+}}x + 3.$

Since it has a limiting value of 3 the answer should be $6$. However when I checked my solution it was wrong, the answer provided was $-\infty$. I have checked on wolfram alpha and my simplification is right but I am not sure where else I have made a mistake. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is neither $6$ nor $-\infty$.

Comment: @mohan10216 are you not familiar with chain rule of differentiation?

Comment: Not by memory. But yes, I just haven't done differentiation for a while.

Comment: Chain Rule: $f(g(x))'=f'(g(x)\cdot g'(x)$, so $(\ln(x^2-9))'=\frac 1 {x^2-9}\cdot (x^2-9)'=\frac {2x}{x^2-9}$

Comment: @MarianG Is that possible? Wouldn't I get the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$ since $ln(0)$ is undefined?

Comment: Actually let me try something.

Comment: @mohan10216: Sorry, mea culpa. I overlooked an important detail.

Comment: @MarianG: Oh lol, I was trying to change log bases and make simplifications and stuff, though none of it really lead to anything haha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am not sure where else I have made a mistake

observe that the derivative of $\log(x^2-9)$ is wrong, being $\frac{f'}{f}$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\log(x^2-9)=\frac{2x}{x^2-9}$$

**EDIT**: Applying de l'Hôpital ONCE (and simplifying the resulting expression) you get 1 as result of your limit

Comment: But isn't the derivative of $ln(x) = \frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: @mohan10216 : Yes it is! But it is not your case. Check the derivative formula for $\ln(f(x))$

Comment: Ahhh ok, I completely forgot about that. Then should this also be the case for the numerator?

Comment: maybe product rule will help @mohan10216

Comment: @mohan10216 : this is the general case. In your numerator your formula is right because $f'=1$

Comment: @tommik Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @tommik: Could you explain why should one use de l'Hôpital's rule twice?

Comment: @MarianG. :  yes sorry, one passage is enough, I forgot to simplify the expression...but applying it twice the result is the same

Answer (score 3):

I would not use L'Hopital's Rule in this case.

I would use the laws of logarithms to rewrite the expression as:

$\frac {\ln(x-3)} {\ln (x-3) + \ln (x+3)} = \frac 1{1 + \frac{\ln(x+3)}{\ln(x-3)} } \to \frac 1{1 + \frac 6{-\infty}} \to \frac 1{1 + 0^-} = 1$

Comment: How do you get the second step?

Comment: @mohan10216 Basically express it as the reciprocal of the reciprocal. $y = \frac 1{\frac 1y}$. When you use it on a rational expression like $\frac a{b+c}$, this allows you to split the rational expression. Fairly standard technique.

Comment: Didn't think of that. Another weapon in my arsenal(I don't mean actual weapons btw).

Comment: @mohan10216 lol. I actually remember first seeing this manipulation in a school physics textbook. I think it was proving the gain formula for an idealised operational amplifier. But I remember thinking: "now that's nifty!".

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\ln(x^2-9)=\ln(x-3)+\ln(x+3)$ so the reciprocal of your function is
$$
\frac{\ln(x-3)+\ln(x+3)}{\ln(x-3)}=1+\frac{\ln(x+3)}{\ln(x-3)}
$$
and the limit of the final fraction is $0$, as it is “$3/(-\infty)$”.

Thus both you and your book made some mistake, because the limit is $1$.

I don't know what the book did, but you computed wrong the derivative of the denominator: if $f(x)=\ln(x^2-9)$, then
$$
f'(x)=\frac{2x}{x^2-9}
$$
by the chain rule or by applying $f(x)=\ln(x-3)+\ln(x+3)$ and finding
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{x-3}+\frac{1}{x+3}=\dfrac{x+3+x-3}{(x-3)(x+3)}
$$
(but we used here the chain rule again, don't overlook it).

Hence, after applying l'Hôpital, you get
$$
\frac{\dfrac{1}{x-3}}{\dfrac{2x}{x^2-9}}=\frac{1}{x-3}\frac{(x-3)(x+3)}{2x}=\frac{x+3}{2x}
$$
Always do the algebra before going again with l'Hôpital: in this case blind application to the “four story fraction in $\infty/\infty$ form” would lead to nothing.

---

Just as a curiosity: if you have a limit of the form
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\ln(f(x))}{\ln(g(x))}
$$
in an indeterminate form, where
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=l
$$
exists finite and nonzero and l'Hôpital assumptions apply, then we can apply l'Hôpital to the given limit and we need to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=l\frac{1}{l}=1
$$
Therefore, also
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\ln(f(x))}{\ln(g(x))}=1
$$

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation , I understand now :). (I should probably also email the author about their mistake lol)

Comment: @mohan10216 I added a general method to show that your limit *must* be $1$.